# Creating a Front end with R

Tags: r, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am storing my data in S3 bucket provided from Amazon. I am performing analytics in R studio by creating instance.

I am storing my desired result back in my S3 bucket.

I would like to create an front end in visual studio for my results in R. Could anyone guide me on how I could proceed with this ?

I have created the AWS explorer in visual studio.

Any lead and guidance for this idea would be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered Shiny as an alternative to a VB front end? It's very easy to create front ends using R & if you don't want to set up the server to serve your Shiny web pages, you can get an account at shinyapps.io

Answer (score 2):

[image: Shiny]

But seriously, take a look at [shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/)

Plagiarizing from that link: "Shiny is an R package that makes it easy to build interactive web apps straight from R. You can host standalone apps on a webpage or embed them in R Markdown documents or build dashboards. You can also extend your Shiny apps with CSS themes, htmlwidgets, and JavaScript actions."

Answer (score 0):

Options (not in any order):

1. [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) is an R package that makes it easy to build interactive web apps straight from R
2. If front-end is all about reports/dashboard, you can push your results in [ElasticSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) and then use [Kibana](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/kibana/) on top to present the results as a dashboard.

HIH